# Rails Sprockets::CircularDependencyError with asset_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets

In my application, I have javascripts, with a refer to default.html. I.e.

```
function link() {
  var url = '<%= asset_path("sidenav/default/default.template.html") %>';
}
```

This works, but, when I use the same to refer with asset_path in another file, i.e. a html (.html.erb of course, and last script, too is a .js.erb), I receive the error Sprockets::CircularDependencyError. A example of html

```
<a ng-href="<%= asset_path('sidenav/default/default.template.html') %>">Default</a>
```

If I dont use the reference to default in javascript, html works, but if I use the same refer in multiples files, this error occur.

Any help?

Comment: what is the exact error, can you copy paste instead?

Comment: of course, here the error in console

https://gist.github.com/darlanmendonca/75e7bda66208da5be7c8de2be736f599

Comment: are you referring it in this file? angular/sidenav/sidenav.directive.js.erb

Comment: yes, in sidenav.directive, and in default.template.html